# Add Image in listView using image from url Picasso crash in android

Tags: android, json, listview, url, picasso

Bonjour
I have spent days and night looking for an answer suitable to my case
can you help please
Here is the code I am using
anytime I add the ligne with Picasso, the program crashes
It works fine with static images from drawable
I just want to display the text with the image that corresponds

```
    public void Afficher_les_vues(String url_in) {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url_in)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                myResponse = response.body().string();
                Annonces.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {


                        try {
                            JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(myResponse);

                            JSONArray eglises = reader.getJSONArray("Annonces_adv");


                            arrayList.clear();


                            for (int i = 0; i < eglises.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject eglise = eglises.getJSONObject(i);
                                String titre = eglise.getString(titret);
                                String description = eglise.getString(descriptionet);
                                int ref = Integer.parseInt(eglise.getString(reft));
                                String image = eglise.getString(imaget);
                                String url_image = eglise.getString(imaget);

                                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();


                                data.put(titret, titre);
                                data.put(descriptionet, description);
                                data.put(reft, String.valueOf(ref));
                                data.put(imaget, image);
                                data.put(url_imaget, url_image);

                                arrayList.add(data);


                                ImageView imageViewlogo = findViewById(R.id.imageViewLogoNews);
                                //Picasso.get().load(url_image).into(imageViewlogo);

                                //new GetImageFromUrl(imageViewlogo).execute(url_image);


                                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Annonces.this, arrayList, R.layout.listview_layout
                                        , new String[]{titret, descriptionet, reft, url_imaget}, new int[]{R.id.titre_de, R.id.description_de,
                                        R.id.reference, R.id.url_image});


                                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                });


            }
```

When I use Picasso to display and image in a simple ImageView not in a listView, it works fine

Thank you in advance
I work with android studio
Blessings

Comment: Where is your adpter class... This functionality working fine right... Where it's happening share those code here

Comment: If the program crashes, look in the logcat tab to find the error and stack trace. Always include these in your question.

Comment: Is `R.id.imageViewLogoNews` in your main layout or the list view row? If the latter, that is your problem. Your call to findViewById there will always return null.

Comment: Also, you should not create and set the adapter inside the for loop... do that after you have completed filling `arrayList`...

Comment: Ok thanks for  the help... I dont konw if I am writing in the right place but... how can  I put the set adapte rand the arrayList outside the loop? sorry I am a beginer in android.... the R.id.imageView is not in the main layout.. it is in a single_item layout that is call by the main layout... how can I fix that? you gave me food for thought....  I will try to send some log info .... thank you again ... blessings

Comment: I updated the answer to include the full CustomAdapter that you would need to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main things you need to fix are not creating the adapter every loop instance and not accessing row views (the ImageView) from outside the adapter.

**1. Do not make the adapter inside the loop**

You should build the array of data to display first, then after the loop that builds the array create the adapter and set it on the ListView. When you have a custom adapter, it is helpful to use a small data class to hold the data you need to show in each row (see `RowData` later in the answer)

```java
arrayList.clear(); // ArrayList<RowData>()

for (int i = 0; i < eglises.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject eglise = eglises.getJSONObject(i);
    String titre = eglise.getString(titret);
    String description = eglise.getString(descriptionet);
    int ref = Integer.parseInt(eglise.getString(reft));
    String url_image = eglise.getString(imaget);

    RowData data = new RowData(titre, description, String.valueOf(ref), url_image);

    arrayList.add(data);
}

// You CANNOT access row view here - in this context findViewById searches the main
// view heirarchy, and will not find views in your ListView rows

// Make the adapter *AFTER* the loop where you fill the array
// you will need to make your own custom adapter to load the image
ListAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(Annonces.this, R.layout.listview_layout, arrayList);


lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**2. Do not attempt to access row views outside the adapter**

Your row views should only be accessed inside `getView` in your adapter itself. This is where you should load the image. If you were using a standard adapter before, you will need to implement your own custom adapter to do this. There are instructions for how to do that [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView). The adapter below takes an ArrayList of `RowData` items and uses that to populate each row.

```java
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData> {
    private Context mContext;
    private int mResource;

    public MainAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<RowData> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mContext=context;
        mResource=resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        if( convertView == null ) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
        }

        // Get the views for this row (these must be in the
        // layout xml you passed in to the adapter constructor)
        TextView title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.titre_de);
        TextView description = convertView.findViewById(R.id.description_de);
        TextView reference = convertView.findViewById(R.id.reference);
        ImageView imageViewlogo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewLogoNews);

        // Get the RowData class for this row
        RowData data = getItem(position);

        // Set the text fields
        title.setText(data.title);
        description.setText(data.description);
        reference.setText(data.reference);

        // Start Picasso loading into the ImageView for this row
        Picasso.get().load(data.url).into(imageViewlogo);
        
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Make a small data class**

When you have a custom adapter it is useful to make a custom data class that holds the data you want to show in each row. This avoids the possible errors in missing keys etc... you can get with a plain old map or passing in multiple lists.

```java
public class RowData {
    final String title;
    final String description;
    final String reference;
    final String url;

    RowData(String title, String desc, String ref, String url) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = desc;
        this.reference = ref;
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```